# Not able to set up Azure AD B2C on .NET Web Forms

Tags: c#, webforms, azure-ad-b2c

I'm currently not able to set up Azure AD B2C on .NET Web Forms

I could set up in MVC or .NET Core in no more than 5 minutes but we have a legacy and I can't do this in another tech.

I have followed [this reference](https://github.com/Zen3InfoSolutions/B2C-WebForms-DotNet) and just changed to my current config and got 500 error, once I click sign up or sign in buttons.

```
<add key="ida:Tenant" value="aicdb2c.onmicrosoft.com" />
<add key="ida:ClientId" value="{application_id}" />
<add key="ida:AadInstance" value="https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration?p={1}" />
<add key="ida:RedirectUri" value="http://localhost:58851/" />
<add key="ida:SignUpPolicyId" value="B2C_1_sign_up" />
<add key="ida:SignInPolicyId" value="B2C_1_sign_in" />
<add key="ida:UserProfilePolicyId" value="B2C_1_edit_profile" />
```

The message error is not helpful. It's just a generic message: "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred".

After getting this message, if I hit enter in the address bar (http://localhost:58851/), I can access the page normally. Otherwise, I just get a blank page with this message.

I have Googled a lot and no luck.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Take a network trace in chrome browser and look at the response to your web app from b2clogin.com. Is a token being returned in this response? Have you tested your user flow inside the portal? Use a redirect uri of https://jwt.ms to test and it’ll show you the token if it works. My suspicion is you created the wrong type of application registration so you don’t even see the sign in page.

Comment: Hi @JasSuri,

Yes, a token is being returned and I have tested the user flow inside the portal. It seems to be working fine. This is the user flow endpoint: https://aicdb2c.b2clogin.com/aicdb2c.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1_sign_in&client_id=ef354479-458f-48e3-bd4f-a4ad313ebac7&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fjwt.ms%2F&scope=openid&response_type=id_token&prompt=login

Also, I used jwt.ms as redirect URI to test and the token works.

Did I set up the wrong type of application? How can I check that?

Thanks!

Comment: @AllexRocha are you working over the very same github repo you shared or using it as a template for another one?

Comment: @Alfredo-MSFTIdentity I did both and did not work.

Answer (score 1):

I found what was causing the issue.

The reference from GitHub is 3 years old and the ida:AadInstance was no longer valid.

It should be like the following:

```
<add key="ida:AadInstance" value="https://aicdb2c.b2clogin.com/{0}/{1}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration" />
```

Please note that you should change aicdb2c to your name / domain.